# How to extract repeating rows in a matrix

Tags: r

I R I have this matrix

```
> Y
>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,] "0"  "2"  "9"  "5" 
[2,] "4"  "7"  "7"  "3" 
[3,] "1"  "5"  "7"  "9" 
[4,] "7"  "8"  "7"  "4" 
[5,] "7"  "8"  "7"  "4" 
[6,] "1"  "1"  "7"  "2" 
[7,] "7"  "8"  "7"  "4" 
...
```

From this matrix I want to get all the repeating rows that repeat 1 time, 2 times, 3 times and so on.

So for example

> "7"  "8"  "7"  "4"

occurs 3 times in Y. How do I find all the other cases?

So the output should be:

**Return all rows that occurs 2 times in Y.**

**Return all rows that occurs 3 times in Y.**

**Return all rows that occurs 4 or more times in Y.**

I have tried to solve this with the

```
> duplicate
```

command but this is not enough.

Comment: Please make a reproducible example with dput() and explain expected output better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple solution based on concatenating the rows of your matrix into a string and then tabulating the frequency with which the strings appear.

First we'll generate some simple fake data. I generate random zeros and ones to ensure there will be plenty of duplicates:

```r
Y <- matrix(rbinom(100, 1, .5), ncol = 4)
head(Y)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    1
#> [2,]    0    0    0    0
#> [3,]    0    0    0    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1
#> [5,]    0    1    1    0
#> [6,]    0    0    1    0

# I collapse all the values in each row into a string, so c(0,1,0,1) becomes "0101"
row.ids <- apply(Y, 1, paste, collapse = "")
# Now using table() I can get the frequency with which each pattern appears
row.freqs <- table(row.ids)

# All triply replicated rows
Y[row.ids %in% names(row.freqs[row.freqs==3]),]
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    0    0    1
#> [2,]    0    0    0    1
#> [3,]    0    1    1    0
#> [4,]    0    0    0    1
#> [5,]    0    1    1    0
#> [6,]    0    1    1    0

# All quadruply replicated rows
Y[row.ids %in% names(row.freqs[row.freqs==4]),]
#>       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#>  [1,]    0    0    0    0
#>  [2,]    0    0    0    0
#>  [3,]    0    0    1    0
#>  [4,]    0    0    1    0
#>  [5,]    0    0    0    0
#>  [6,]    0    0    1    0
#>  [7,]    0    1    1    1
#>  [8,]    0    1    1    1
#>  [9,]    0    1    1    1
#> [10,]    0    0    0    0
#> [11,]    0    1    1    1
#> [12,]    0    0    1    0
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Using the test matrix `Y` in the Note at the end, use `aggregate` to create a data frame `ag` whose rows are the unique rows of `Y` followed by the count of how many times they occur.

```
ag <- aggregate(cbind(count = apply(Y, 1, toString)) ~ ., as.data.frame(Y), 
  FUN = length)

nc <- ncol(Y)
subset(ag, count == 2, select = -count) # shows rows which occur twice

split(ag[1:nc], ag$count) # splits unique rows into those that occur once, twice, etc.
```

### Note

```
Y <- matrix(c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1), 25, 4)
```